# Error parsing XML, line 2152, column 10: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: xml, blogger, head

Please help. I'm not sure what "entity" the error refers to. I've tried to copy the answers from previous questions similar to this but i think it depends on the html. I know it's not that complicated but I am new to this so I'm not familiar with tweaking the html of an existing blogger template.

I appreciate prompt answers.

Comment: Where's the XML file?

Comment: this is the last part:
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(d){
  var f = d.getElementsByTagName(&#39;SCRIPT&#39;)[0], p = d.createElement(&#39;SCRIPT&#39;);
  p.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;;
  p.async = true;
  p.src = &#39;//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js&#39;;
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
}(document));
</script>
</b:if>
</div>
</style>
  </b:if>
  </head>

Comment: Please edit the snippet into question and indicate where "line 2152, column 10" is.

Comment: please let me know if you need the whole of the xml file. not familiar how this works.

Comment: i'll send as question. just a sec

Answer (score 1):

An XML entity for the purposes of this message is an [external parsed entity](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xmlnut/ch03_05.htm). That is, a blob of XML sitting off in some other location that is being incorporated into your XML via a DTD definition. The error is telling you that a start (`<something>`) and its corresponding end (`</something>`) must live inside the same entity -- the original main XML input, or one external incorporated item. You can't start in one and end in another.